# XMLPullParser: FileNotFoundException when trying to open a stream

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I would like to parse a XML file using a XMLPullParser. The code is:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(false);
XmlPullParser myxml = factory.newPullParser();

InputStream raw = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("etat_cree.xml");
myxml.setInput(raw, null);
```

The file "etat_cree.xml" is a basic XML file I only created to test my code. The problem I have is that a FileNotFoundException is launched whenever I try to create the InputStream raw variable as if the file wasn't found.

I saved the file "etat_cree.xml" inside the directory "res/xml" (I saved it in "res" because it is a resource file and in the sub-directory xml because it is a XML file).

As the XML file is not found, I guess "res/xml" is not the right place to save it but I do not know where else to save it.

So my question is, where should I save the XML file so that I could access it from the Java code ?

Thanks !

Comment: You've called `getApplicationContext().getAssets()` so your file must be in `/assets` forlder of your project!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in the assets folder or sub folders of the assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in the assets folder or sub folders of the assets folder.and also
try this links[xml parsing in android](http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94)